# opened dialog window in windows service

Tags: windows, service

I am running some Windows application as a service. This application used Office applications(Word, Excel). The service runs under specific user account.
Here is the problem: 
When service is trying to use Excel, Excel is showing some dialog window which blocks the application from running. Since it's a service running in noninteractive mode you are not able to see the dialog window.
I was wondering if there is a way to get the title of a dialog window to understand the root cause of it.
I tried using EnumDesktopWindows but it didnt help.

Platform: Windows 10.

Thanks